# gradle - replace text inside the XML file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to replace some keywords(kind of variables) inside the XML. We are migrating Ant build to Gradle. One of the files is XML which contains some keywords, something like ${FILE_ID}, ${GROUP_ID}. I need to read this XML file and replace those keywords with actual values.

```
def dest = file("pom/module-pom.xml")
def text = new File('pom/dependencies.pom').text
text = text.replaceAll("${GROUP_ID}", "${groupId}")
dest.write(text, "UTF-8")
```

The problem is that Gradle recognizes '${GROUP_ID}' as gradle property. Is there a way to have Gradle treat this as a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use single quotes where you don't want a replacement to occur. Eg:

`text.replaceAll('${GROUP_ID}', groupId)`

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Mr. Hakis Blog](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/08/groovy-goodness-string-strings-strings.html):

> If we use a double quoted string and it contains an Groovy expression with the ${expression} syntax we have a GString.

As the above link states, there are several ways to declare a simple `String` instead of a `GString`, e.g. to simply use single quotes. Also, please note, that your problem is caused by a Groovy feature rather than by a Gradle feature. So, the `${expression}` syntax will not only work for Gradle (project) properties, but any Groovy expression.